# How to check if whether a string is all lowercase?

Tags: swift

I've got the code below. I want the string to be capitalized if the user input is all lowercased. Does swift offer this feature? I know in Python is ".islower()". I tried googling, I tried typing `.is` and seeing what comes up, but no luck.

```
let holder = PasswordCoreData(entity: PasswordCoreData.entity(), insertInto: context)

if let title = createHolderItem.text {
    holder.item = title

    //here is where I need help
    if holder.item.[islowercased] {
        holder.item = holder.item.capitalized
    }
    holder.username = createHolderUsername.text!
    holder.password = createHolderPassword.text!
}
```

Comment: You can safely force-unwrap the `.text` property of `createHolderItem`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can safely define `title` this way `let title = createHolderItem.text!` without the `if let` optional binding construct

Answer (score 4):

Check if `title` is equal to the lowercased version of `title`.

```
if title == title.lowercased() {
    // It's an all lowercase string
}
```

You can make a helpful little extension:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isLowercase: Bool {
        return self == self.lowercased()
    }
}
```

Now use it as:

```
if title.isLowercase {
}
```

Comment: I get into an issue with this. Because if I change it within another if statement, it's no longer a constant. And ```if var``` doesn't unwrap the object

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Yabusa `.lowercased()` is not a mutating function. Still it is constant

Comment: Sorry there was an issue in my code. "title" was supposed to be "holder.item". So the ```if let``` statement is to unwrap ```createHolderItem.text```. If I try to use another if statement within it to see if ```if title == title.lowercased()```, it shoots back an error that I cannot change it to capitalized because it's a constant. I need to safely unwrap it without making it a constant

Comment: @Yabusa Change `let holder` to `var holder`

Comment: Tried. ```if var``` doesn't unwrap

Answer (score 1):

For letters in the english alphabet (from lowercase **a** to lowercase **z**) you could verify that `title` is lowercase by checking that all the Unicode scalars

```
let scalars = title.compactMap { $0.unicodeScalars.first?.value }
```

do [satisfy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy) this condition:

```
let isLowerCase = scalars.allSatisfy({ $0 > 96 })  //true
```

The Unicode scalars of **A** to **Z** go from 65 to 90. You can check them this way :

```
"A".unicodeScalars.first?.value` //65 
"Z".unicodeScalars.first?.value` //90
```

As to lowercase letters they go from 97 to 122:

```
"a".unicodeScalars.first?.value  //97 
"z".unicodeScalars.first?.value  //122
```

For more on Unicode scalars, have a look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID293).

---

A more succint solution (suggested by **@rmaddy**), that covers accented letters and letters from other alphabets, is to check the [`isLowercase`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127012-islowercase) property of all the characters:

```
let isLowerCase = title.allSatisfy({ $0.isLowercase })
```

Comment: Why restrict this to the letters a-z? What about accented letters and letters from other alphabets?

Comment: Why not use the `isLowercase` property of `Character` or `Unicode.Scalar.Properties`?